# Click on a cell, the image size changed

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I am setting the imageview size to be fixed. I have set the constraint in the storybard, and the constraint is correct. But after I loading some images from the web service, when I click on the cell, some of the images changed it's size, some of them don't. I have set the image view contentMode to aspect fit. How to make the image auto resize to fit in the imageview, and I don't have to click on the cell, to make it resize to fit?

The cellForRow:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    LocalCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[LocalCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *photoReference = [self.restaurants[indexPath.row][@"photos"] objectAtIndex:0][@"photo_reference"];
    NSString *photo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=80&photoreference=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", photoReference, AppKey];

    cell.name.text = self.restaurants[indexPath.row][@"name"];
    cell.desc.text = self.restaurants[indexPath.row][@"vicinity"];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photo] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please show your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method too.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your image that pops outside of your UIImageView?

Comment: try to set clipsToBounds as YES;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 80, 50);
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your UIImageView **clipsToBounds** propery to **YES** as below

**[yourImageView clipsToBounds:YES];**